# Why doesn't my funtion print anything?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a funtion in Python that makes a dictionary from all the words in a file and their corresponding encryption (that follows from the function encrypt_password). The funtion doesn't give an error, but it isn't printing the password dictionary as well. Where am I going wrong?

The input now looks like this:

```
import hashlib

def encrypt_password( passwd ):
    """Encrypt a plaintext password (a string). It returns the result.
    This encryption is one-way only, meaning it is not easy (impossible) to decrypt
    the encrypted password to find out the original plaintext password again."""
    return hashlib.sha256( passwd.encode() ).hexdigest()

keys = open('words.txt').read().splitlines()

values = []

for i in keys:

    e = encrypt_password(i)

    values.append(e)

password = dict(zip(keys, values))

print(password)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need `print(Passwords)` instead of `print(password)`

Comment: Is there a typo? There's no password in your code. You need to print(Passwords)

Answer (score 0):

You have variables Passwords, password in different spellings. What does password refer to?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Ah yes I just saw that and I changed it, but it still isn't printing anything. Password is the dictionary of the words from the file and the encrypted version of the words I am trying to make

Comment: Perhaps words.txt is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a typo: the passwords dictionary is first called 'Passwords' and next 'password'. Probably you meant:

```
passwords = dict(zip(keys, values))

print(passwords)
```